# Unable to Dynamically Edit Reference Values within Query Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if it is possible to create a dynamically changing range within the `QUERY` function?

Below is the formula that is currently working, with a static range in the first reference of the Query `($A$2:$AO$11)`

```
=QUERY('External Tab'!$A$2:$AO$11,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Account" ,'External Tab'!$A$2:$AO$2,0),4),1,""))
```

Ideally, I would be able to have the `11` value dynamically change, based on the number of rows that contain either `Live` or `Pending` in their row. That way, when the query is pulled, it returns a specific number of rows from that table.

As it stands now, if the table it is referencing is edited to be longer than 11 rows, it will not pull in all of the data. I also can't put an arbitrarily large number in there to account for this, as the query will then start to pull in data further down the worksheet that I don't want to see.

[image: pic of current query]

In trying to troubleshoot this, I am able to get the number of rows by using 2 `COUNTIF` formulas together:

```
=COUNTIF('External Tab'!A:AO,"Live")+COUNTIF('External Tab'!A:AO,"Pending")
```

In the above example, this standalone formula returns a correct value of '10'. Ideally, this would dynamically make the range in the query `$A$2:$A:10` (instead of the static `11` it currently has). Is it possible to nest the result of this formula to make the row reference in the range dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Use offset + your countif solution.

Do:

```
=QUERY(OFFSET('External Tab'!$A$2,0,0,(COUNTIF('External Tab'!A$1:AO$65536,"Live")+COUNTIF('External Tab'!A$1:AO$65536,"Pending"))-1,1),"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Account" ,'External Tab'!$A$2:$AO$2,0),4),1,""))
```

Note that I had put a "-1" there since the needed value to feed to offset is 10 if the number of items is 11.

Have a try. ( :

Please share if it works/not/understandable.